# Could not deduce template argument / None of the 'n' overloads could covert all argument types

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to compile a vector library called vmath by Jan Bartipan.

There are a few functions that extend the `std` namespace for vector that look like this:

```
#define VEC3 Vector3

namespace std
{
    //...

    template <typename T>
    VEC3<T> min(const VEC3<T>& a, const VEC3<T>& b)
    {
        return VEC3<T>(::std::min(a.x, b.x), ::std::min(a.y, b.y), ::std::min(a.z, b.z));
    }

    //...
}
```

`x`,`y` and `z` are members of Vector3 and are of type `T`.

When I try to compile this code, I get the following error:

```
error C2784: 'Vector3<T> std::min(const Vector3<T> &,const Vector3<T> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const Vector3<T> &' from 'const double'
```

I looked around online and found that perhaps the call to `std::min` needs to be templated. So I tried changing the code to the following:

```
template <typename T>
VEC3<T> min(const VEC3<T>& a, const VEC3<T>& b)
{
    return VEC3<T>(::std::min<T>(a.x, b.x), ::std::min<T>(a.y, b.y), ::std::min<T>(a.z, b.z));
}
```

But when I try to compile this, I get the following error:

```
error C2665: 'std::min' : none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

I'm hoping you all can shed some light on what I'm doing incorrectly.

Thanks!

EDIT: I am using Visual Studio 2013 to compile

Comment: Have you included `<algorithm>` which defines `std::min`?

Comment: I downloaded vmath, used VC 2012, seems to compile. I sense, based on the error message, that the answer may be how you've USED the new min function. I created two Vector3<double> and a third to receive the return from min...no compiler issue.

Comment: @immibis No I had not included it. Including it solves the problem. If you write an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Adding overloads to `std` causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you don't include `<algorithm>` where `std::min` is declared, your definition of `std::min(const VEC3<T>&, const VEC3<T>&)` only sees itself.

And so `std::min(a.x, b.x)` try to match the only possible overload `std::min(const VEC3<T>&, const VEC3<T>&)` and can't as `a.x` is `double`.

`#include <algorithm>` should solve your problem.